# How could i get all values out?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-in-loop, for-of-loop

Here is the assignment I have. Declare a function `getAllValues`. You may need to use both kinds of for loops!

```
/**
* @param {Array} ???
* @returns {Array} an array of all of the values in all of the given objects
*/
function getAllValues(arrayOfObject){ 
    let arr = [];
    for(const e of arrayOfObject){
        let obj = arrayOfObject[e];
        for(const key in obj){ 
            arr.push(obj[key]) ;
        } 
    }
    return arr;
}

// test
test(getAllValues(collection), [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 100]); // returns []
test(getAllValues(collection.slice(1)), [3, 3, 4, 100]); // returns []
```

What's wrong with my current code?

Comment: The function is small enough that you should be able to step through it line by line in the debugger to see what goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the error is here:

```js
let obj = arrayOfObject[e];
```

Here the variable e itself is the object from the array, not an index. So it should be:

```js
let obj = e;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I should have not overthought of it, it's a such a simple code!